# Правильно получить приходящее время

Tags: java, android

С сервера приходит ответ в котором указано время в пути.
Суть в том, что иногда приходит в таком виде 45 ( то есть понимается что 45 минут)
А иногда приходит 00:45 
Вопрос как привести ответ к определенному виду?

Comment: `if (string.indexOf(':') == -1) string += ":00"; // 45 => 45:00` - такой вариант подойдёт?

Comment: Да, спасибо , то что нужно)